# Divergent limit cycle frequency along a hopf boundary

Tags: bifurcation

I am studying the linear stability of continuous system as a function of two parameters (a and b) and I observe that a hopf bifurcation with frequency w happens along the line described by f(a,b). Now, it turns out that there is a critical point (a_c, b_c), for which w=infinity along the line f(a,b). As the points approach (a_c, b_c) from one side the frequency diverges.
I suspect a bifurcation at (a_c, b_c), but I can not identify the right name to look it up. From what I know, this looks like some route to chaos but I don't see how it can lead to a continuously increasing frequency w along f(a,b). Any ideas on how to characterize and understand this transition are welcome.

Thanks in advance,

M

Comment: I thought about this, too. But the Feigenbaum constant describe the ratio of iteration steps, as in the article you link. In my case there are no discrete iteration steps also I don't see any frequency-doubling with discrete frequency steps, it is "continuous" divergence.